Discord.py every command doesn't work only on_message(message):
I know discord.py is kinda old but like 2 years ago i discovered this and decided to try code, kinda lost it and month ago retry coding
So i have this strange error beacose while i was codding tree comands i delete something and my commands stopped working
Spent 2 days to find solution but still the same
Here is part of code:
Main.py
`import datetime
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions

from client import client
from fun import ocena
from moderation import delete, usun_kanal, dodaj_kanal
from spaming import ghost, spam, stop, spam_error


@client.command()
async def pfp(ctx, *, avamember: str = None):
    if avamember is None:
        await ctx.send("Musisz oznaczyć użytkownika!")
        return

    try:
        avamember = await commands.MemberConverter().convert(ctx, avamember)
    except commands.MemberNotFound:
        await ctx.send("Nie mogłem znaleźć tego użytkownika!")
        return

    user_avatar_url = avamember.display_avatar.url
    await ctx.send(f"**Awatar użytkownika** {avamember.name}: {user_avatar_url}")


@client.command()
async def ocenka(ctx):
.......

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if ctx.message.content.count('.') <= 1:
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
            await ctx.send("Podano złą komende! ⚠️")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("Witaj! Aby zobaczyć liste moich komend wpisz `.help `! ")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,
                                 activity=discord.Game(name="Wpisz .help by zobaczyć co mogę dla ciebie zrobić!"))
    print('------------------------------')
    print('Pomyślnie zalogowano jako:')
    print("Nazwa bota:", client.user.name)
    print("Id bota:", client.user.id)
    print("Bot został uruchomiony", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    print('------------------------------')


client.run(`yk`)

client.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.',intents=intents)
tree = client.tree

client.remove_command('help')


Rest of files are commands but pattern is basicly the same
from command import command
@client.command()
async def command(ctx):
await command(ctx)
I have twice @client.command() for command
First in main.py :
@client.command
async def delete(ctx, name):
    await delete(ctx, name)

Second in command.py:
@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def delete(ctx, count):
    try:
        count = int(count)
        if (count < 0):
            await ctx.send("wrong number")
            return
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send("error")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{count} messages")
        deleted_messages = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=count + 1)


I save this "method" or "schema" on some old youtube tutorial so i decided to do the same
ready for down arrows 

Does this answer your question? Why does on_message() stop commands from working? Tu masz rozwiązanie ;)

dziękuje bardzo mam teraz inne problemy ale rozwiązało to problem !! :) jeszcze raz dziękuje
